# Trying to get an overlay to toggle on a repeating element. Can't use getElementByID

Tags: html, reactjs, create-react-app, masonry

As per the title I want an overlay to trigger when an image is clicked on, but I then want it to disappear if anywhere other than 3 buttons on the overlay are clicked.

Unfortunately using getElementbyID won't work as the items repeat on a masonry layout.

```
    <Masonry
    breakpointCols={breakpointColumnsObj}
    className="my-masonry-grid"
    columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column">
      
      {this.state.data.map((data) => (
        <div>
          <div className="tilebutton" key=""  style={{width:'100%',position:'relative'}} href={data.URL} >
              <div className="tileoverlay" id="overlay" onClick={overlayoff} onclickout key={data.URL} style={{display:'none',width:'100%',zindex:'2',position:'absolute'}}>
                <a className="button1" href={data.URL} onClick>{data.Name}</a>
                <a className="button2" href={data.CompURL}>{data.Company}</a>
                <a className="button3" href={'instagram.com/'+data.insta}>{data.Company}<img src="\img\Icons\instagram.svg" className='instalogo'/></a>
              </div>
              <img src={data.img} onClick={overlayon} style={{width:'100%'}}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </Masonry>
  )
  
function overlayon() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function overlayoff() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

Unfortunately using the id "overlay" means if I click any version of the masonry it will trigger the overlay on the first image. Is there some way to:

a) identify the element clicked so it will be the one with the toggling overlay

b) have an "onclickout" I could apply to the overlay's buttons

this is about 5 days into my first ever web build so frankly I haven't got a clue what I am doing - any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idioms used in React discourages you to manipulate the DOM directly, unless you are doing something special, such as animation. And thus I don't recommend "identifying the element clicked".

With that said, you can manipulate the data, and trigger a redraw accordingly, by invoking some `setSate` function (in the example below, I've defined a `setShouldShowOverlay`, that, when invoked, will result in a redraw).

What I recommend is for you to pull out the code inside `this.state.data.map()` into its own component, like so:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Data({ data }) {
  const [ shouldShowOverlay, setShouldShowOverlay ] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="tilebutton" key=""  style={{width:'100%',position:'relative'}} href={data.URL} >
          <div className="tileoverlay" id="overlay" onClick={() => { setShouldShowOverlay(false); }} onclickout key={data.URL} style={{display:'none',width:'100%',zindex:'2',position:'absolute'}}>
            <a className="button1" href={data.URL} onClick>{data.Name}</a>
            <a className="button2" href={data.CompURL}>{data.Company}</a>
            <a className="button3" href={'instagram.com/'+data.insta}>{data.Company}<img src="\img\Icons\instagram.svg" className='instalogo'/></a>
          </div>
          <img src={data.img} onClick={() => {
            setShouldShowOverlay(true);
          }} style={{width:'100%'}}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then finally, update your Masonry code like so:

```js
<Masonry
  breakpointCols={breakpointColumnsObj}
  className="my-masonry-grid"
  columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column">
    
    {this.state.data.map((data) => (
      <Data data={data} />
    ))}
</Masonry>
```

Comment: That works an absolute treat, thankyou so much.

You wouldn't have an answer for how to set for onclickaway as well would you?

Also I'm on 13 reputation, so know that I have upvoted you it just won't show until I'm a little more respectable.

Thanks again! Really appreciated!